# Using PyQGIS processing runalg clipvectorsbypolygon

Tags: pyqgis, clip, qgis-processing

I try to use clip vector by polygon in pyqgis.

My code (minimal working example)

```
import sys
from qgis.core import *
import qgis.utils


QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr",True)
qgs = QgsApplication([],True)
qgs.initQgis()

# load base layer
blayer = QgsVectorLayer("lokale_orte.shp", "lokale_orte", "ogr")
if not blayer.isValid():
        print "Layer failed to load!"
else:
        print "success:  load layer"


# load clip layer
clayer = QgsVectorLayer("kleine_kreise.shp", "kleine_kreise", "ogr")
if not clayer.isValid():
        print "Layer failed to load!"
else:
        print "success:  load layer"


# Prepare processing framework 
sys.path.append('/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins') # Dir where Processing is located
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
from processing.tools import *


# run clip
general.runalg('gdalogr:clipvectorsbypolygon', 'lokale_orte.shp',                 'kleine_kreise.shp', None, None)
```

The complete output and error message is:

```
success:  load layer
success:  load layer

Error in sys.excepthook:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 196, in qgis_excepthook
    showException(type, value, tb, None, messagebar=True)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 107, in showException
    open_stack_dialog(type, value, tb, msg)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 142, in open_stack_dialog
    iface.messageBar().popWidget()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'messageBar'


Original exception was:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 34, in <module>
    general.runalg('gdalogr:clipvectorsbypolygon', 'lokale_orte.shp', 
'kleine_kreise.shp', None, None)

  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/tools/general.py", line 75, in runalg
    alg = Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, None, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing
/core/Processing.py", line 300, in runAlgorithm
    ret = runalg(alg, progress)

  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing
/gui/AlgorithmExecutor.py", line 52, in runalg
    progress.error(e.msg)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'error'
```

I guess my problem is the **runalg** call, according to http://docs.qgis.org/2.6/de/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/ogr_geoprocessing/clipvectorsbypolygon.html

I think I can write None for output layer to force QGIS to write the output in an memory layer. But what about options? What to write? Where is a proper documentation?

Comment: Are you running it as a standalone script?

Comment: yes. It is not part of an qgis extension. Basically it works, general.alglist creates the proper output.

Comment: versions: python: 2.7; qgis: 2.16; OS: Ubuntu 16.4

Comment: So, you only want to call the output from the general.runalg (i.e. the last operation of your code) as a memory output?

Comment: yes. I want to iterate over all features in the output layer and do some calculations. I think a memory output is enough. But the basic input layer (lokale_orte.shp in the example script) has thousands of features, so i like  to clip it to get a usable subset.

Comment: Please, see my solution: it works from inside QGIS, but I can't test it right now using a standalone script. Let me know if it works also for you.

Answer (score 1):

You may continue using the memory layer by loading it as an *object*. Before doing this, you need to know how the output from the algorithm is called, so typing these lines in the Python Console:

```
import processing
processing.alghelp('gdalogr:clipvectorsbypolygon')
```

you will see that the output's name is `OUTPUT_LAYER`:

```
ALGORITHM: Clip vectors by polygon
INPUT_LAYER <ParameterVector>
CLIP_LAYER <ParameterVector>
OPTIONS <ParameterString>
OUTPUT_LAYER <OutputVector>
```

This means that you will be able to use it if you add a new variable and call it in this way:

```
# change 'my_algorithm' name as you want
my_algorithm = general.runalg('gdalogr:clipvectorsbypolygon', 'lokale_orte.shp', 'kleine_kreise.shp', None, None)

# change 'my_output' name as you want
my_output = processing.getObject(my_algorithm['OUTPUT_LAYER'])
```

By now, `my_output` will be the object to use for calling the layer returned by the clip operation and you are ready to do something with it.

**EDIT** For getting your script working, you may try using the following code (slightly different from yours):

```
import sys
from qgis.core import *
import qgis.utils

qgs = QApplication([], True)
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

# Prepare processing framework 
sys.path.append('/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins') # Dir where Processing is located
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
from processing.tools import *
Processing.initialize()

# load base layer
blayer = QgsVectorLayer("path/to/the/shapefile/lokale_orte.shp", "lokale_orte", "ogr")
if not blayer.isValid():
    print "Layer failed to load!"
else:
    print "success:  load layer"

# load clip layer
clayer = QgsVectorLayer("path/to/the/shapefile/kleine_kreise.shp", "kleine_kreise", "ogr")
if not clayer.isValid():
    print "Layer failed to load!"
else:
    print "success:  load layer"

# run clip
# change 'my_algorithm' name as you want
my_algorithm = general.runalg('gdalogr:clipvectorsbypolygon', 'lokale_orte.shp', 'kleine_kreise.shp', None, None)

# change 'my_output' name as you want
my_output = processing.getObject(my_algorithm['OUTPUT_LAYER'])

QgsApplication.exitQgis()
qgs.exit()
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Generating a memory layer is now much clearer for me. But I still get the same error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'error'

Comment: @dlg_ are you sure that the output from the `'gdalogr:clipvectorsbypolygon'` is correctly created? Maybe there is some other error before this operation?

Comment: OK, I checked it. Everything befor calling runalg works fine. Even processing.alghelp('gdalogr:clipvectorsbypolygon') works. So I don't think that there is an issue by loading the library.

Comment: So, nothing is returned if you write `print my_output`?

Comment: No. I checked this, but the script terminates with exactly the same error message as I wrote in the question. I checked also clipping the shapefile from qgis user interface which works fine. There might be no problem with the input files.

Comment: What about `print my_algorithm`?

Comment: Still the same problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58086/discussion-between-mgri-and-dlg).

Comment: @dlg_ please, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will make a CRS reference before clipping.

```
# PostGIS SRID 4326 is allocated for WGS84
crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.PostgisCrsId) 
my_algorithm = general.runalg('gdalogr:clipvectorsbypolygon', 'lokale_orte.shp', 'kleine_kreise.shp', None, None,rcs)
```