# pyQGIS 3.0 script not running with processing import

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, qgis-3, osgeo, standalone

I have problems using version 3 of QGIS with Python 3. I followed different tutorials like this one :
[how to use pyqgis processing runalg clipvectorsbypolygon](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/238944/how-to-use-pyqgis-processing-runalg-clipvectorsbypolygon)

But it seems to be working only with QGIS 2.XX and not 3.0. Here is what I try to run :

```
from qgis.core import *
import PyQt5.QtCore

import sys
sys.path.append('C:/QGIS 3.0/apps/qgis/python/plugins')

qgs = QgsApplication([], True)
qgs.setPrefixPath("C:/QGIS 3.0/apps/qgis", True)
qgs.initQgis()

import processing

qgs.exitQgis()
```

But I get on PyCharm the error message : "Process finished with exit code 1".
I don't understand what is missing in my code. Can you please explain me how to use processing library with independent pyqgis scripts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding the following line to my code :

```
sys.path.append("C:\\QGIS 3.0\\apps\\Python36\\Lib\\site-packages")
```

In fact when I tried to interpret my python script with PyCharm the problem was that I didn't get any information about my mistake. I ran it with the basic IDLE for Python 3 and it said me `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osgeo'` which means the link to the library is not done because osgeo is installed with QGIS. The link to the library is what I wrote above.

**BUT** notice that you could also add this path to your %PYTHONPATH% variable. You mustn't do that because the folder `site-packages\` contains many other libraries that can confuse Python executables like `pip`.

Answer (score 5):

I tested your code and stripped the problem down to the paths you are using. The error seems to be the forward slashes (**/**) that confuse your windows python installation. You should use backslashes on windows and use them as escaped symbol (eg. double backslash **\**). I updated your code with the paths of my system (an OSGeo4W64 installation), you can change them to match your directory structure:

```
from qgis.core import *
import PyQt5.QtCore

import sys

qgs = QgsApplication([], True)
qgs.setPrefixPath("C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\qgis", True) 
#should be C:\\QGIS 3.0\\apps\\qgis

qgs.initQgis()

sys.path.append('C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins')
# should be "C:\\QGIS 3.0\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins" in your system

import processing


qgs.exitQgis()
```

Now the script should work. Sidenote: I ran the script from OSGeo4W Shell using the `python-qgis` command (python interpreter with QGIS paths). In case PyCharm still throws some errors, try running your script there or in PyDev (Eclipse). For reference: There is a [similar answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/279937/33338) to this one that also shows how to call native c++ algorithms from python.

Comment: I always have the same issue... Ok for the paths but I think my problem comes maybe from the Windows global path. Can you give me what you have in PC path concerning python and qgis ? Thank you for your help.